# One value should be at status 'ACTIVE' and all others should be 'DISABLED'

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle9i

I want to display the username whose name starts with a- and status should be 'ACTIVE' for specific system id other than that all status should be 'DISABLED' for the same system id.

Below table is used to display the records:
[image]

person_id, admin_person_id and username_id are the primary keys for these three tables.

If I take the domain_id(LKJHC)  its person_id is 5678  in the ADMIN_Person table the corresponding person id's username_id's are there in that username id have many system ids but here I want only status 'ACTIVE' for system_id 123 and username starts with (a-)  but other than all the 123 system_id's are disabled except username starts with a- with 'ACTIVE' status.

The query which i used:

```
SELECT e.domain_id,e.username,e.system_id
FROM (SELECT p.domain_id,u.username, u.status, u.system_id 
     FROM username u  JOIN admin_person up ON u.username_id = 
     up.username_id JOIN person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
     WHERE  u.  username LIKE 'a-%'
     AND u.status = 'ACTIVE'
     AND u.system_id = 123) E
     WHERE e.domain_id IN  ( SELECT p.domain_id
            FROM username u
            JOIN admin_person up ON u.username_id = up.username_id
            JOIN person p ON up.person_id = p.person_id
            WHERE u.status = 'DISABLED'
            AND  u.system_id = 123)
```

In this result i am getting the 123 active usernames also without username starts with -a. like(adsf)

Comment: If some `system_id` has `username = xyz` and `status = ACTIVE`, should that `system_id` be displayed?

Comment: @Vashi:    I need that specific 123 system_id only ...for that 123 id has usename=xyz  with active status that domain_id should not be displayed.

Comment: Not able to understand what you are trying to have done. Can you try running the query without that WHERE condition outside `WHERE e.domain_id IN ( .....)

Comment: For the specific domain_id there must be a number of usernames and system_id's here i want to display only  for the domain whose status is active for system_id 123 and username should starts with "a-"  with "ACTIVE" status and all other usernames belong to that domain_id should be disabled.

Comment: Okay got your point

Comment: What if there were two entries of `a-lily` with one of them active and other disabled? Do you still want that domain_id to show?

Comment: @Vashi:  Yes i want to display the domain_id.  username a-lily which has active status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161965/discussion-between-vashi-and-madhan).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161991/discussion-between-vashi-and-madhan).

Answer (score 0):

I have used the logic of counting the instances of violation of your rule  `(U.USERNAME NOT LIKE '%-a' AND U.STATUS = 'ACTIVE') OR (U.USERNAME LIKE '%-a' AND U.STATUS = 'DISABLED')` for every `DOMAIN_ID` and only if this count is 0 is when the `DOMAIN_ID` will be kept.

```
SELECT P1.DOMAIN_ID, U1.USERNAME, U1.SYSTEM_ID
FROM 
PERSON P1 INNER JOIN ADMIN_PERSON AP1 ON P1.PERSON_ID = AP1.PERSON_ID
INNER JOIN USERNAME U1 ON AP1.USERNAME_ID = U1.USERNAME_ID
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT P.DOMAIN_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN (U.USERNAME NOT LIKE '%a-' AND U.STATUS = 'ACTIVE') OR (U.USERNAME LIKE '%a-' AND U.STATUS = 'DISABLED') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NOT_ELIGIBLE
    FROM
    PERSON P INNER JOIN ADMIN_PERSON AP
    ON P.PERSON_ID = AP.PERSON_ID
    INNER JOIN USERNAME U
    ON AP.USERNAME_ID = U.USERNAME_ID
    GROUP BY P.DOMAIN_ID) A
ON P1.DOMAIN_ID = A.DOMAIN_ID
AND A.NOT_ELIGIBLE = 0
AND U1.USERNAME LIKE '%a-';
```

After `DOMAIN_ID` is filtered, the query should pick the `USERNAME` with `a-` format.

Comment: I ran this query no values were returned (Null Result). But i have many domain_id statisfy the condition.Please help on this.Thanks for your support

Comment: This query is working but it is also  pulling the domain id which has active  status (USERNAME) and USERNAME does not starts with "a-"

Comment: Would you be able to share the output of the inner query that I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Get the `count` values individually for `Username not like 'a-%'` and `Status = 'DISABLED'`

in the *nested inner SQL* and equalize them for the *outer part of SQL* :

```
SELECT domain_id,username, system_id
  FROM
 (
  SELECT ( SELECT count(1) 
             FROM Username 
            WHERE Username not like 'a-%' ) cnt_not_equals_a,
         ( SELECT count(1) 
             FROM Username 
            WHERE Status = 'DISABLED' ) cnt_equals_disabled,
         p.domain_id,u.username, u.system_id   
    FROM username u
    JOIN admin_person a ON ( u.username_id = a.username_id )
    JOIN person p ON ( a.person_id = p.person_id )  
   WHERE u.Username like 'a-%' 
     AND u.Status = 'ACTIVE'
     AND u.system_id = 123
 )
 WHERE cnt_not_equals_a = cnt_equals_disabled;

 DOMAIN_ID  USERNAME    SYSTEM_ID
 ---------  ---------   ---------
  LKJHC      a-lily       123
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c5974/15)